# None (pronoun) : "not any" vs. "no part, nothing"

Tags: pronouns, dictionaries, any

The entry of **none** distinguishes

> PRONOUN
>
> 2. not any, as of something indicated: ***None** of the pie is left. That is **none** of your business*.
> 3. no part; nothing: *I'll have **none** of your backtalk!*
>
> https://www.wordreference.com/definition/none

I don't understand the difference between both meanings though.

Answer (score -1):

Word reference is not the best of dictionaries, it might help you for a quick look up of a word, but for an in-depth understanding of a word's meaning it may be insufficient. As for the definition under [3.], there is an informal phrase: ***have none of (something)***.
[Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/have-none-of) says:

> ***have none of***
> phrase
> If you say that someone will *have none of something*, or *is having none of something*, you mean that they ***refuse to accept*** it.
> [informal]
>
> - He knew his own mind and ***was having none of their attempts*** to keep him at home.

[Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/have-none-of-sth) agrees:

> to refuse to accept, agree with, or support something:
>
> - She tried to
>   persuade him to retire, but he ***would have none of*** it.

Comment: https://oed.com/oed2/00159141

Comment: I get your point, it is not easy to figure out this was a phrase. I agree. That's why I am grateful for internet search engines. Their suggestions can really help sometimes.